# Django html variable inside a json string

Tags: html, json, django

I have a json string that contains a variable.

```
"country": {
    "name":"England",
    "city":"London",
    "description":"This country has a land mass of {{ info.1 }}km² and population is big as <span class=\"colorF88017\">{{ info.2 }} millions</span>.",
    "info":[
        null,
        [130395],
        [5479]
    ]
}
```

As you see those variables are linked to a list in the json file. But when i do in the template html: `{{ country.description }}` It does not show what `info.1 or info.2` contains. It just display everything as a text.

How can i display the value from a variable inside a string?

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
def country_info(request):
    context = {}

    show = request.GET.get("show")
    if show:
        context["country"] = get_country_json()

    return render(request, 'country_info_index.html', context)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where this json is created? is it in views file?

Comment: No json is fetched from a website api

Comment: How are populating this in api? in api you need string contactination, but you are not doing that. And value in `{{ country.description }}` will always be pure text for django template

Comment: Sorry my fault, i mean from a json file in a cdn online. I read the json from the backend and render it in the frontend. 

Ofcourse it shows the description but does not populate the `info.1 or info.2`

Answer (score 2):

Use `render_to_string` pass the arguments like follow

```
description_template.html:
This country has a land mass of { info.1 }km² and population is big as <span class=\"colorF88017\">{ info.2 } millions</span>.
```

use this template in render_to_string

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
template_name = "description_template.html"
description = render_to_string(template_name, 
  context={
     "info": description
  }
)
```

or using f string

```
description =  f"This country has a land mass of { info.1 }km² and population is big as <span class=\"colorF88017\">{ info.2 } millions</span>."
```

Comment: I dont really understand, can you explain bit more. Also description seems not being used. Also i use the shortcut `render` which seems to use `render_to_string `

Comment: @Printer It parses the string before passing it to the template.

Comment: @dan-klasson My computer internet is gone, so i can't test it right away. But should i make a templet filter and Passing the description as value and return it as render_to_string

Comment: @Printer Yes, that would be the better option in terms of separation of concerns. But either way works.

Comment: Cheers man, will give it a try and Hopefully it will work. Just need wait for my internet to come back.

Comment: @dan-klasson it give me the error: TemplateDoesNotExist

Comment: @Printer sorry my  mistake create a template with the content and put template name instead of  actual string

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan can you provide me an example. I didn't really get it :/

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan thanks for updating the post. Can you check my first post. I've updated it with how the backend send info. Since i cant figure out how i will do it with what you provided :/